# Benq G2420HDBL + Radeon RX580: blank screen

Tags: display, amd-radeon, blank-screen

Benq G2420HDBL works fine with Radeon R9 270. But when I connect it to the computer with Radeon RX 580 some bad things happened: in BIOS setup it works fine and shows all texts and graphics up to Windows loading. Then - blank screen. Other manufacturer monitors work with R9 270 and RX 580 correctly all the time.
Connection type: DVI. OS: Windows 10 Pro. Driver versions: I have tried various drivers and fresh OS installing too.
How I could solve this problem? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation: Windows/driver try to set incorrect display regime for your monitor (usuall incorrect resolution and refresh rate).

There are two the simplest ways to solve your problem:

1. Link you computer (it will be 1st computer) to the working monitor. Install on it and another computer (it will be second) any program for remote admin/remote assistance (ammyy admin, for example). Connect to the 1st computer from the 2nd using that program. Now turn off and unlink your working monitor (the 1st computer must work!) then link your Benq G2420HDBL. From the 2nd computer go to the screen settings and set correct resolution and refresh rate.
2. Link your computer to the working monitor via DisplayPort and to your Benq G2420HDBL as second monitor. Now you have working monitor as the first, go to the settings, and correct correct resolution and refresh rate for your Benq G2420HDBL. After correction turn off the computer and unlink the 1st monitor.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! The 1st way did help. Now all is OK.